# Interface in other languages

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams, localization

It would be great if the interface of Stack Overflow for Teams could be changed to other languages (German, French, etc.). In some organizations that might facilitate the introduction of Stack Overflow for Teams. Is this possible? I tried unsuccessfully.